# awk insert lines/records in a flagged print from match

Tags: awk, gawk

Awk program shall process many datafiles. In each datafile it shall look for pattern and insert two lines / records with new field.
(This is is only an example. The final program has to do more things next to this action).

datafile(s) as example

```
Rec not needed-1
Rec not needed-2
Rec not needed-n
start
Record-1
Record-2
Record-n
```

It is tab-delimited and here we have only $1.

source program

```
BEGIN { OFS=FS="\t"}

FNR==1 {flag=0;} p; 
#flag && $1!=""{$1=$1; print}

$1=="Record-2" && flag{$1="";$2="newline1"; print; $1=""; $2="newline2"; print}
#$1=="Record-2" {flag=1} p {$1=""; $2="newline1"; print; $1=""; $2="newline2"; print; flag=0} 1

flag!=0{print};
/start/{flag=1}
```

Since I use Windows this is called via GAWK.

wanted output:

```
Record-1
        newline1
        newline2
Record-n
```

my output with issue of dublication of "newline2"

```
Record-1
        newline1
        newline2
        newline2
Record-n
```

The problem I think is related to the use of "flags". But in order to execute all other actions of my awk program in work the

```
FNR==1 {flag=0;} p; 
...    
flag!=0{print};
/start/{flag=1}
```

Should remain untouched - as long it won't 'harm'. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please add more clear sample Input_file and expected output file here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, because of the `flag`, the last

```
flag!=0{print};
```

is doing an extra print, so you could remove the last print in `$1=="Record-2" ...`:

```
BEGIN { OFS=FS="\t"}

FNR==1 {flag=0} 
#flag && $1!=""{$1=$1; print}

$1=="Record-2" && flag{$1="";$2="newline1"; print; $2="newline2"}
#$1=="Record-2" {flag=1} p {$1=""; $2="newline1"; print; $1=""; $2="newline2"; print; flag=0} 1

flag!=0{print}
/start/{flag=1}
```

Another option could be to add another condition to the `flag`, but don't know if this will mess up your script:

```
BEGIN { OFS=FS="\t"}

FNR==1 {flag=0} 
#flag && $1!=""{$1=$1; print}

$1!="Record-2" && flag!=0 {print}

$1=="Record-2" && flag{$1="";$2="newline1"; print; $2="newline2"; print}
#$1=="Record-2" {flag=1} p {$1=""; $2="newline1"; print; $1=""; $2="newline2"; print; flag=0} 1

/start/{flag=1}
```

Or:

```
BEGIN { OFS=FS="\t"}

FNR==1 {flag=0} 
#flag && $1!=""{$1=$1; print}

$1=="Record-2" && flag{$2="newline1"; print "\t"$2; $2="newline2"; print "\t"$2}
#$1=="Record-2" {flag=1} p {$1=""; $2="newline1"; print; $1="";    $2="newline2"; print; flag=0} 1

$1!="Record-2" && flag!=0{print}
/start/{flag=1}
```

Comment: I works. I opt at the moment for the 1st solution, where I ommit the print. Anyhow, I will have a closer look at the other solutions. Thank you alot.